# Difference between "בני העיר" and "בני המדינה"

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

Shu"a [C"M 231, 27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.231.27?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> "**רשאים בני העיר** לקוץ להם שער לכל דבר שירצו ולהתנות ביניהם שכל מי שיעבור קונסים אותו כך וכך: "

ibid 15:

> "**בני מדינה** שרצו להוסיף על המדות או על המשקלות לא יוסיפו יותר על שתות"

Is there a difference between the two and if yes, why?

Comment: If I remember médina is a region of the yr. See the mishle about atsel, and the order yr, Medina, Rehovoth,

Comment: @kouty You speak in codes I cannot decipher. Can you please write Hebrew words in Hebrew.

Comment: העצל הוא רך הלבב, ואינו גולה למקום תורה. ועליו אמר שלמה המלך שבעה דברים (דברים רבה ח ו). כיצד?

    אומרים לעצל: "רבך בעיר, לך ולמד תורה הימנו!" והוא משיב להם: "מתיירא אני מן הארי שבדרך", שנאמר (משלי כו יג): "אמר עצל שחל בדרך".
    אומרים לו: "רבך בתוך המדינה, עמוד ולך אצלו!" והוא משיב להם: "מתיירא אני שלא יבוא ארי בתוך הרחובות", שנאמר (שם): "ארי בין הרחובות".
    אומרים לו: "הרי הוא דר אצל ביתך!" והוא משיב להם: "הארי בחוץ", שנאמר (שם כב יג): "אמר עצל ארי בחוץ, בתוך רחובות ארצח".

Comment: @kouty I see this is from Orchot Tzadikim, what's the source and what does it prove? Is it consistent with Gemmorah, Rambam and ShuA?

Comment: Source דברים רבה 8.6.

Comment: עיר מגיל מדינה, מדינה מכילה רחובות, רחוב מלכי בית

Comment: @kouty how the shua can be explained if anything?

Comment: This is not an answer, I did just point a difference between yr and Medina,, that Medina is a part of the yr, from the midrash